# typeset equations with matrix plus annotations

Tags: equations, matrices

I would like to typeset an equation like shown in the pic. 
[image]

I know how to typeset the equation

```
\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix} \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} \end{bmatrix}
 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} &
   X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
   X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} &
   X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12} 
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
```

But have no clue how to add the annotation to make the equation look like exactly the one shown in the pic. Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean `annotation` as `M`, `W` and `T`??

Comment: @MadyYuvi, well everything shown in the pic needs to be replicated through tex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `nicematrix` it is very easy to obtain such an output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcommand{\Vdashes}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
\draw[densely dashed] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\[
 \Vdashes\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC}[first-col,code-for-first-col =\scriptstyle,
 name=M,
 code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (2-1.south) -- (2-2.south) node[midway,below=1em]{$\mathsf{M}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}] 
 \mathsf{a}:&\Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ 
 \mathsf{b}:&\Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} 
 \end{bNiceArray}\Vdashes
 \begin{bNiceArray}{CC}[name=W,
 code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (2-1.south) -- (2-2.south) node[midway,below=1em]{$\mathsf{W}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}] 
  \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ 
  \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} 
 \end{bNiceArray}
 =\Vdashes
 \begin{bNiceArray}{CCC}[first-col,code-for-first-col =\scriptstyle,
  name=T,
 code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (2-1.south) -- (2-2.south) node[midway,below=1em]{$\mathsf{T}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}] 
  \mathsf{a}:& X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} &
   X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
  \mathsf{b}:& X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} &
   X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12} 
 \end{bNiceArray}
 \Vdashes
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Per request. Not sure if I personally like these underbraces but it is easy to add them. (At least the `=` sign is at the correct vertical position.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
 \underbrace{\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC}[first-col,
 code-for-first-col =\scriptstyle] 
 \mathsf{a}\mathrlap{:}&\Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ 
 \mathsf{b}\mathrlap{:}&\Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} 
 \end{bNiceArray}}_{\textstyle =M}
 \underbrace{\begin{bNiceArray}{CC} 
  \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ 
  \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} 
 \end{bNiceArray}}_{\textstyle =W}
 =
 \underbrace{\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC}[first-col,code-for-first-col =\scriptstyle] 
  \mathsf{a}\mathrlap{:}& X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} &
   X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
  \mathsf{b}\mathrlap{:}& X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} &
   X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12} 
 \end{bNiceArray}}_{\textstyle =T}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can shrink the `a` and `b` column further if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
 \underbrace{\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC}[first-col,
 code-for-first-col =\!\!] 
 \mathsf{a}\mathrlap{:}&\Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ 
 \mathsf{b}\mathrlap{:}&\Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} 
 \end{bNiceArray}}_{\textstyle =M}
 \underbrace{\begin{bNiceArray}{CC} 
  \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ 
  \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} 
 \end{bNiceArray}}_{\textstyle =W}
 =
 \underbrace{\begin{bNiceArray}{CCC}[first-col,code-for-first-col =\!\!] 
  \mathsf{a}\mathrlap{:}& X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} &
   X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
  \mathsf{b}\mathrlap{:}& X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} &
   X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12} 
 \end{bNiceArray}}_{\textstyle =T}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: would you please replace the dotted line with the braces under matrix as suggested by @Zarko? Also how can I change the spacing between : and [ at both side of the equation as well as that at both sides of =?

Comment: @user1935724 Sure, I added them. Not sure if I'd use them personally, though, I like your original picture better (with all its aspects, including a densely dashed line, but this is all a matter of taste).

Comment: very nice thanks a lot! I'd like to further improve it though, how do I make a, b larger and also how to control the space between ] and = also the space between = and a:( and b:)

Comment: @user1935724 If you drop the keys `code-for-first-col =\scriptstyle` then `a` and `b` will become larger.  If you replace `=` by `~=~`, say the space around the `=` will become larger.

Comment: actually I am using `\!` to shrink the space between = and a: but braces got shifted as well which now starts covering = how can I fix that ?

Comment: @user1935724 I added another version, based on the comments. Is that what you want?

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `arydshln` and `nicematrix`, but no explicit Ti*k*Z.

Fix the figures in the `\rule` command to suit you. The optional argument sets the amount of space under the baseline (that's the line passing through the bottom of the equation number) and the second mandatory argument specifies the *total* height of the rule. With the given code there are 50pt below the baseline and 40 above.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,arydshln,nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\matrixname}[2]{% #1 = number of columns to span, #2 = name
  \multicolumn{#1}{C}{\mbox{\Large$#2\smash[b]{\vphantom{\Bigl|}}$}}%
}
\begin{array}[t]{: @{}c@{} : @{}c@{} : @{}c@{} :}
\rule[-50pt]{0pt}{90pt}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col,last-row]
\mathsf{a:} & \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\
\mathsf{b:} & \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} \\
            & \matrixname{2}{\mathsf{M}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
&
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[last-row]
\Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\
\Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} \\
\matrixname{2}{\mathsf{W}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
={}&
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col,last-row]
\mathsf{a:} & X_{11}Y_{11}-X_{12}Y_{21} & X_{22}Y_{12}-X_{12}Y_{22} \\
\mathsf{b:} & X_{11}Y_{21}-X_{21}Y_{11} & X_{11}Y_{22}-X_{21}Y_{12} \\
            & \matrixname{2}{\mathsf{T}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may liked more standard way of annotation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, blkarray}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \underbrace{\begin{blockarray}{r[cc]}
a: &    \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ 
b: &    \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22} 
             \end{blockarray}}_{\bf{M}}
 \underbrace{\begin{blockarray}{[cc]}
        \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22}
            \end{blockarray}}_{\bf{W}}
 =
 \underbrace{\begin{blockarray}{r[cc]}
a: &    X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} & X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
b: &    X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} & X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12} 
    \end{blockarray}}_{\bf{T}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way that I can control the space between : and [ at both side of the equation as well as that at both sides of =? Thanks

Comment: @user1935724, so far I didn't found the way. Sorry. T my opinion answer which propose `nicematrix` is way to go. It can be easily adopt to use braces below matrix as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Already gave many nice suggestions, but consider this one may suits with you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{matrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
M
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
W
\end{matrix}
 =
\begin{matrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} &
   X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
   X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} &
   X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12}   \end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
 T
\end{matrix}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array,arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{array}{:c:}
 \begin{bmatrix} \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
M
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
 \begin{bmatrix} \Phi_{11} & \Phi_{12} \\ \Phi_{21} & \Phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
W
\end{array}
 =
\begin{array}{:c:}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   X_{22} Y_{11} - X_{12} Y_{21} &
   X_{22} Y_{12} - X_{12} Y_{22} \\
   X_{11} Y_{21} - X_{21} Y_{11} &
   X_{11} Y_{22} - X_{21} Y_{12}   \end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
 T
\end{array}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Is this meets the requirement?